# Unable to delete my answer

Tags: bug, status-review, answers, deleted-answers

I wrote [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76917657/1491895) to a SO question. Then I learned that I misunderstood the question, so I tried to delete my answer. The confirmation dialog popped up, I clicked on OK, but it wasn't deleted.

The answer isn't accepted, so that's not the problem.

I opened the browser console, I didn't see any errors. I also tried turning off all my extensions in case there's a conflict.

I'm able to edit the answer, so I replaced it with text explaining this problem.

Comment: Possibly a silly question (and no harm intended) but is it possible you're not logged in or are logged in with a different account? Do you have any userscripts running? Is it something you can reproduce on another machine or browser? Have you deleted several other posts today already?

Comment: Also, I apparently can't read (regarding userscripts). Apologies!

Comment: More questions - have you tried deleting any other answers (and undeleting if it works). How many times have you tried to delete the answer? I'm willing to delete the answer for you but that's not necessarily going to solve the underlying issue if there is one.

Comment: I just successfully deleted and undeleted this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12237595/1491895 But I still can't delete the one that prompted this question.

Comment: FWIW : at this moment, there's no "Barmar-written" visible answer for a standard user (without rep/privilege to see deleted answers).

Comment: Despite the comment saying VLQ reviewers should skip that answer, they voted to delete it. Can/should a mod undelete it? @Catija

Comment: I think that it'll be OK - our logs should show your attempts to delete (hopefully). I don't have access to them since I'm not a dev. This may be a situation that is transient for some reason that we won't be able to diagnose but since I don't see other people indicating they're having this issue, it seems like we're OK for the time being. I'd say if you (or anyone) has this happen again, we should probably do a bit more digging.

Comment: Next time I answer I'll see if I can delete it. Shouldn't be long.

Comment: I just successfully posted and deleted an answer to this question.

Answer (score 12):

I did check in with a dev to look at the error logs and it seems like we coincidentally had a bunch of SQL timeouts around the time you reported this bug. That means that while we do see your attempts to delete the post, they didn't go through.

Since you have been able to delete other posts, the post can be (has been) deleted, and I don't see other people stating they are still experiencing this with other posts, so this seems like a transient issue.

Thanks for bringing it to our attention and please let us know if you experience any further issues.

Comment: Thanks. Just FYI, the problem persisted for at least an hour. I didn't post the question until I'd tried several times and did a little searching in MSO and MSE to see if it had already been reported. And I tried again after your comments.

Comment: It's still happening. I just tested trying to delete https://stackoverflow.com/a/76925551/1491895 and it failed.

Comment: Sorry about that @Barmar - I'll see if we can check whether the same issue caused this or whether there's something else going on.

Comment: @Barmar we aren't sure exactly what's causing the issue but it's likely related to the coincidence that you're trying to delete a post at the same time we're running a bunch of daily updates (it's been midnight UTC both times you've reported being unable to delete). It's also possible that there's some relation to your SO profile having so many posts - but we're not quite certain. I will say that it's unlikely other people will run into this and you likely won't on sites other than SO - so we may have trouble isolating the issue. I'll update if we find anything.

Comment: @Barmar I took a pretty hard look at this last night and could not reproduce the issue, as Catija said, there seems to be a perfect storm here, I'll have to step through the application code with a dev because I couldn't identify the issue in the database alone.

Comment: Thanks for investigating. I just retried deleting that answer and it worked this time, so the timing reason seems plausible. I'm familiar with this kind of problem; we also have daily update jobs that cause significant delays. We do them in early morning US time.

Comment: While it may be difficult to resolve the root cause, could we at least get it to display an error message when this happens? "Database timeout, please try again later."

Comment: It's happening again now, and it's 2 hours before midnight UTC.

Comment: The answer I'm trying to delete now is https://stackoverflow.com/a/76932707/1491895. I've tried several times over the last 30 minutes.

Comment: It just happened again with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77160893/1491895). But this time, after a few seconds I get a popup saying something like "An error has occurred. Please try again". Needless to say, retrying doesn't work.